# rsync: how to perform safe 2-way sync local<->remote webdav?

Tags: macos, sync, rsync, webdav

I have two directories:

- `/Volumes/webdav/` — mounted remote WebDAV disk
- `~/files` — local copy

I'd like to perform 2-way sync (manual) between them. What I'm doing:

```
$ rsync --exclude='.gitconfig' --exclude='*~' --exclude='.DS_Store' -varP ~/files/* /Volumes/webdav/ --delete
```

And vice versa (/Volumes/webdav/* ~/files/).

### Questions

1. What's the difference between `~/files/ /Volumes/webdav/` and `~/files/* /Volumes/webdav/`? In first case I'm getting:

   ```
   building file list ...
   4498 files to consider
   ```

   in second:

   ```
   building file list ...
   1382 files to consider
   ...
   ```
2. Sync logs often shows somehting like:

   ```
   building file list ...
   4498 files to consider
   .es/
   .es/�\#232а�\#200�\#202а Саи�\#206�\#202а.doc
          20480 100%    0.00kB/s    0:00:00 (xfer#1, to-check=4486/4498)
   .hb/
   .hb/25-512.png
          39036 100%    5.98MB/s    0:00:00 (xfer#2, to-check=4482/4498)
   .hb/icon-white-menu.png
           1546 100%    1.47MB/s    0:00:00 (xfer#3, to-check=4481/4498)
   .hb/icon-white.png
          26858 100%    0.00kB/s    0:00:00 (xfer#4, to-check=4480/4498)
   .pt/Untitled/
   .pt/session0/
   .pt/speed1/
   .pt/speed1/Session File Backups/
   .var/
   .var/DSC_6545.jpg
        4595455 100%   92.58MB/s    0:00:00 (xfer#7, to-check=4198/4498)
   .var/book_edit.pdf
   ...
   ```

   So, rsync shows some progress in transferring files, but if I start command again, it shows the same — transfers the same files, traverses the same folders, etc. Does it actually transfers something? If yes, why every time?

Thanks.

Comment: You aren't showing the full run string. Are you using `-u`? Is the file time resolution the same on the destination volume as the source? Are you using `--modify-window`?

Comment: The difference between `~/files/` and `~/files/*` is that the second will not include `~/files/.*`: `rsync` recursion includes all files in a subdirectory, including dot-files, but using `~/files/*` excludes the dot-files in `~/files/` _before_ recursion; dot-files from subsequent levels of recursion _will_ be included.

Comment: @AFH thank you! I've shown the full string in original message: `rsync --exclude='.gitconfig' --exclude='*~' --exclude='.DS_Store' -varP ~/files/* /Volumes/webdav/ --delete` About file time resolution: it's hard to say for me, cause it's a third-party WebDAV server. On my side I'm using macOS. Also, I've tried Unison file synchroniser and it also fails with `The contents of file have been modified during transfer`, which may point some issues with timestamps, I guess.

Comment: I usually use `ls --full-time` to compare times, but I've a feeling that option doesn't exist on OSX. The other program which shows times with picosecond resolution is `stat`, which you can try on any any one of the files and its back-up copy. This will tell you if the time-stamps are identical, or if not how many seconds to use with `--modify-window`: 1 or 2 should be adequate.